# What is the difference between HaXe NME and OpenFL?

Tags: libraries

On http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NME_%28framework%29 there is an info:

> NME is an open-source game and application framework that supports
>   iOS, Android, BlackBerry, Microsoft Windows, Mac OS X, Linux, Flash
>   Player and HTML5, with legacy compatibility for webOS.

On OpenFL website ( http://www.openfl.org/about/overview/ ), is this info:

> OpenFL is a software development kit that provides an environment for
>   building fast, native games and applications for iOS, Android,
>   BlackBerry, Windows, Mac, Linux, Flash and HTML5.

The link to the website of HaXe NME (on wikipage), redirects to website of OpenFL, and on that website, is zero informations about HaXe NME, it looks like it doesn't have its own website and any documentation. I have impression that both do kinda the same thing - enable easy compilation to the same platforms, but are clearly two different libraries in haxelib, so - what is the difference between them? How they relate to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what i've understood, OpenFL is basically a better version of NME and has replaced it.

It gives you access to most of the Flash graphics API which is rendered via OpenGL, WebGL etc. depending on the target.

It's higher level on the user side and lower level on the rendering side, improving usability, performance, crossplatform compatibility etc.

As a developer, you needn't worry about the change, you update the imports in your project and it should compile just like NME used to.